# Flutter BLoC library: Where to keep the TextEditingController object: in State, in BLoC / Cubit class or in the widget?

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc, cubit

While using BLoC library we store all the variables in a state class. But where to store TextEditingController, which does not change, but the value of it does?

Let's say I have a state class like this (Just as example):

```
@freezed
abstract class EditItemState with _$EditItemState {
  const factory EditItemState.updated({
    TextEditingController titleController,
    ShoppingItem shoppingItem,
  }) = _ShoppingListLoaded;
}
```

And the Cubit class:

```
class EditItemCubit extends Cubit<EditItemState> {
  EditItemCubit() : super(EditItemState.updated());

  Future<void> titleUpdated() async {
    emit(
      EditItemState.updated().copyWith(
        shoppingItem: state.shoppingItem.copyWith(
          title: state.titleController.text,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So the Cubit class logic looks messy. I suggest to keep such controllers directly in the widget or in BLoC/Cubit class. Is it a correct approach?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2293) guys asked the same question from the library authors and the answer of Felix Angelov (author of flutter_bloc) is:

> I would highly recommend against maintaining TextEditingController as part of the bloc. Blocs should ideally be platform-agnostic and have no dependency on Flutter. If you need to use TextEditingControllers I would recommend creating a StatefulWidget and maintaining them as part of the State class. Then you can interface with the control in response to state changes via BlocListener

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I have kept mine within my Cubit class. The reason for that is because I am more than likely going to be using the result of that controller at some point. To keep things clean I reference the controller's text within the Cubit rather than pass the text through an event.

Another reason is because you are able to subscribe to events, like `addListener`, of the controller within the Cubit, which would be considered "Business Logic".

Comment: That's sounds reasonable, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer has helped you, don't forget to accept it 

Comment: yeah but you can use the onChanged function to call events to your bloc, and listen for state changes in the blocListener property of a BlocConsumer.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice agains using `TextEditingControllers` in blocs or cubits, because for me it's a UI level which shouldn't be passed to the logic above.

The problem with either Animation or Text controllers goes away if you use [hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks). The code inside of a `HookWidget` looks like this:

```
final titleTextController = useTextEditingController(text: book?.title ?? '');
```

I can add listeners to it and call some methods on change or just get current text and don't care about disposal, as it's happening automatically.

Other hooks include `useContext()` or `useState()`. More on hooks in my [Flutter cubits + hooks tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580).

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping it inside Bloc Cubit would be a great option because lets say you have separated Widgets in a page with sections i.e. General Sections, intro sections, in a form. Imagine passing TextEditingController to all the child widget from the parent Widgets. Just keep inside cubit or bloc, wrap the parents widget with blocbuilder and read from anywhere.